# Google Cloud Instance Groups - Canary testing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, update

I am trying to figure out an efficient way of guaranteeing that the new update for the instance group will roll out as intended before actually performing the rolling update of the instance group.

I'm trying to find a way using canary testing which will allow us to flag the instance as healthy and working.

What i am not understanding is how to "exclude" the canary tested machine from the instance group and have a specific route for it set in the load-balancer. This might not be possible?

What i mean is that we do not want any traffic to be directed to the canary tested instance but a specific route to it to perform tests (startup, connectivity, new features ..).

When the canary test is successful a rolling update should be scheduled.

I guess one instance could be temporarily created outside the instance group, but that would not be a good test in the context of the instance group.

Anyone that has had similar problems?

Comment: 1) Create a new Managed Instance Group (MIG) with the new template. Add the MIG to the load balancer. From there you need to figure out how you want to route certain traffic to the new MIG. 2) My preferred method is to create a new MIG and a new load balancer. Once I am happy with the change, move the MIG to the old load balancer. Then adjust for traffic and then remove the old MIG. Scale one down and the other up.

Comment: Isn't there a disruption in traffic when you remove and assign a new MIG to the old load balancer? Currently im just changing the instance template and perform a rolling restart, then i can achieve zero downtime even though traffic gets sent to the both the old and new instances for a short period.

Comment: You add a new MIG first, load balance across the MIGs then scale down the MIG you want to remove. You can also use instance templates. MIGs allow you to use a different load balancer first for isolated testing.

Comment: I'm currently struggling with this as well. How do we guarantee that the changes won't be visible to our users, but only for us developers? Or, how do we guarantee that the changes are visible to certain users only?

The solution to create a new MIG makes the rolling updates useless. Not good.